# Using the "?" operator

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

I have the following code. `abc` and `newdata` are string variables. What it does is add some text to the variable abc and put into variable test.

```
var test = abc + "?ds=" + newdata;
```

I want to change this code so that the following:

```
"?ds=" + newdata;
```

is added only if there is no question mark in the string abc.

Is there a simple way I can do this. I was thinking to use the "?" operator so I could just do this inline but I am not sure how to use that.

Comment: Be careful with the ternary operator. For some things it's fine, but for me, personally, this is approaching the point where I'd switch to using an `IF` statement. When you go to refactor the code or add new functionality, I find complicated ternary statements to be a liability. Remember that the person who maintains your code after you've left the company is a psychotic killer who knows where you live.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should be able to use the ternary operator—`?`—for this.

I think you're looking to add the "?" if none exists already.

```
var test = abc + (abc.Contains("?") ? "" : "?") +  "ds=" + newdata;
```

But if you really only want to add `"?ds=" + newdata;` if no question mark already exists, this should do it

```
var test = abc + (abc.Contains("?") ? "" : "?ds=" + newdata);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is this

```
var test = abc + (abc".Contains("?") ? "?ds=" + newdata : string.Empty);
```

This will append `"?ds="` if and only if `abc` contains a ?.  Otherwise, it just appends empty string.

This is functionally equivalent to this code

```
var test = abc;

if (!abc.Contains("?"))
   test += "?ds=" + newData;
```

So pick your poison, either one is perfectly legible and does the same thing.

Comment: Check your `if` condition. I think you meant `if (!abc.Contains("?"))`. I prefer the `if` in the case over the ternary operator. It just looks cleaner to me.

Comment: Aaaaaaarrhg! At least *my poison* comes with matched braces!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
var test; 

if (!abc.Contains("?"))
    {
        test =String.Format("{0}?ds={1}",abc,newdata);
    }
```